# Teradata 7423 : HY000] Object already locked and NOWAIT. Transaction Aborted

Tags: locking, teradata, blocking

My Teradata version is 15.00.

I got Teradata error 7423: [HY000] Object already locked and NOWAIT. Transaction Aborted, after identify that a table is locked.

-- use this command to test if a table is locked for update/insert/delete.

```
Lock Table DB1.TABLE1 write nowait
Select * from DB1.TABLE1;
```

I have tried a few things but I cannot get the locked table out of its misery.

1. I tried to release the DB archive lock, which is usually the root cause of a blocking issue.  But my own session was blocked by an invisible hand/ghost even ViewPoint cannot detect it.
2. I aborted 2 table update attempts, which I thought was the blocking issue, but did not help

I cannot perform a table update statement due to this table locking issue.

```
UPDATE DB1.TABLE1
SET UpdatedDate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
,LastRunDate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
,Status = 'P'
WHERE PackageID = 100001;
```

I can still select data from this table:

```
Select * from DB1.TABLE1;
```

Thanks for any tips/suggestions.  Really appreciate it.

Comment: If Viewpoint/QUeryMonitor can't show the blocking session it's usually due to a leftover backup lock, did you check using `showlocks` in remote console? Assuming you still run ARC in TD15, how did you try to release it, using an ARC script or a SQL `release lock dbname.tablename, override;`?

Comment: I used SQL on TD Studio:  LOGGING ONLINE ARCHIVE OFF FOR PROD_DB;  But this command was blocked by an unknown process, which ViewPoint could not tell me.

Comment: This probably doesn't remove locks, it simply switches backup mode,thus it was blocked by the ARC lock

Answer (score 0):

I used this SQL and it released the lock on a database:

```
release lock db_name, override;
```

It is interesting that the release archive log did not work:

LOGGING ONLINE ARCHIVE OFF FOR DB_NAME;